# C# How can I read all jpeg files in a directory using a Filestream so the files aren't locked?

Tags: c#

How can I read all jpeg files in a directory using a Filestream so the files aren't locked? My current code is below, there is no mention of Filestream as I can't get it to work. Many thanks for any help.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        images = new List<Image>();
        // add images

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\files\");
        FileInfo[] finfos = di.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (FileInfo fi in finfos)
            images.Add(Image.FromFile(fi.FullName));

   }

    private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        index++;
        if (index < 0 || index >= images.Count)
            index = 0;
        pictureBox1.Image = images[index];
        int count = index + 1;
        labelCount.Text = "Showing " + count.ToString() + " of " + images.Count;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3wke8tz.aspx) and pass `FileShare.ReadWrite`:

```
using (var stream = fi.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    images.Add(Image.FromStream(stream));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the [Image.FromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) method which locks the file. As an alternative you could try to read the contents of the file into a buffered memory stream and then load the image from this stream using [Image.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx).